# urljoin when an absolute path does not have a leading slash

Tags: python, url, url-parsing, urlparse

Some websites like http://www.gilacountyaz.gov/government/assessor/index.php have a bunch of internal links that should be absolute paths, but do not have the leading slash. When parsing them with `urlparse.urljoin` the result is the following:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> a = "http://www.gilacountyaz.gov/government/assessor/index.php"
>>> b = "government/assessor/address_change.php"
>>> urlparse.urljoin(a, b)
'http://www.gilacountyaz.gov/government/assessor/government/assessor/address_change.php'
```

This causes a web crawler to not realize it already visited a page, with a potentially infinite loop. Firefox and Chrome are able to spot the problem and resolve correctly to

```
http://www.gilacountyaz.gov/government/assessor/address_change.php
```

Is there a way to do the same in Python? Note that assuming always a leading slash does not work, because we might be dealing with a genuine relative path.

Comment: How are you expecting to distinguish between a genuine relative path and an accidentally relative path that's missing a `/`? What's the rule behind that distinction?

Comment: I frankly do not know, but Firefox and Chrome are apparently doing it, so I wonder if there is a way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The linked page contains the following:

```
<head>
  <base href="http://www.gilacountyaz.gov/index.php"/>
</head>
```

If you use that URL as the first argument to `urljoin` you'll get the correct result. This tag is what allows your browser to interpret these links correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox and Chrome are both reading the `<base>` tag at the top of the page:

```
<base href="http://www.gilacountyaz.gov/index.php"/>
```

Your code needs to use that as the root:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> a = "http://www.gilacountyaz.gov/index.php"
>>> b = "government/assessor/address_change.php"
>>> urlparse.urljoin(a, b)
'http://www.gilacountyaz.gov/government/assessor/address_change.php'
```